# I could not execute this code , php is running and I have test with sample php , can someone decode??, I have posted the php code and html code also

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Computer Status Checker</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Computer Status Checker</h1>
        <form action="test.php" method="post">
            <label for="ipAddress">Enter IP Address:</label>
            <input type="text" id="ipAddress" name="ipAddress" required>
            <button type="submit">Check Status</button>
        </form>
        <div class="result">
            <?php include('test.php'); ?>
        </div>


    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
    if (!empty($_POST["ipAddress"])) {
        $ipAddress = $_POST["ipAddress"];
        $output = shell_exec("ping -c 1 $ipAddress");
        if (strpos($output, "1 received") !== false) {
            echo "<p style='color: green;'>Computer is ON</p>";
        } else {
            echo "<p style='color: red;'>Computer is OFF</p>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<p style='color: red;'>Please enter an IP address</p>";
    }
}
?>
```

The error message is Cannot POST /test.php

I have tried with xampp and apache is running but no luck
I could not execute this code , php  is running and I have test with sample php , can someone decode??, I have posted the php code and html code also

Comment: Sounds like you are getting a 405 Method Not Allowed error(?), which would indicate that your web server is not correctly set up to handle `.php` files.

Comment: `no luck` isn't an error message or problem statement. I see no reason you couldn't use this with Apache, if you've set it up properly. To know what went wrong we'd need a proper description of the situation, though. See also [ask] and how to make a [mre] of your issue. We cannot see your screen.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have `index.php` or `index.html` with the form and then
the other `test.php` file that is in charge of running the ping command.

#### 1. Is the index a `*.php` file or `*.html` file?

You can only include another PHP file into the index if the index itself
is written in PHP. Is it the case?

Rename `index.html` to `index.php` if it's not the case.

#### 2. Correct the URL of the form action

You are actually loading the `test.php` file into the form page but
also posting the form to this file, which will make you leave the page
with the form itself, and only display the result of the `test.php` file.
Is this really what you want? As you are including it below the form,
I don't think it's what you want.

Replace the URL in the form by

```php
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">
```

or by

```php
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post">
```

In the second option, using `REQUEST_URI`, you'll keep the query
string parameters, if there are some, like `/index.php?page=1`.
And in the first, with `PHP_SELF`, you will only have `/index.php`.

Up to you to decide if you want to keep or drop the query parameters.

I would personally use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.

#### By the way

The content of `test.php` could just be pasted inside `index.php`
so that you only have one single file for your little web tool.

Using *includes* is great when you develop web apps. It helps
you split logic and rendering so that you don't mix up the code
of the app with the HTML output.

But here, for this tiny web page, I don't really see the point of
having 2 files for it. If you keep this `test.php` file, at least
rename it to `ping.php`, so that we know what it is made for.